# Apache Flink async requests and windows

Tags: java, asynchronous, stream, apache-flink

I cannot choose an appropriate windows function/assigner. The task is following. First I get data from a Source with a request_id and some data and perform an asynchronous request to an external database.

```java
// Here String is for request_id, Data is for treated data
DataStream Tuple2<String, Data> stream = ...

// async I/O queries
DataStream<Tuple2<String, String>> resultStream =
AsyncDataStream.unorderedWait(
    stream,
    new AsyncDatabaseRequest(),
    1000,
    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
    100
);
```

Now I want to collect all data by request_id and make some calculations.

```java
DataStream Tuple2<String, Integer> = result
    .map(val -> new Tuple2<String, Integer>(val.f0, val.f1.data_int))
    .keyBy(0)
    .window(...)
    .sum(1);
```

The problem is the window function. I need each window to consist all data points with the same request_id, but times for async queries may vary from millisecs to minutes. On the other hand I need low latency, so I cannot use `ProcessingTimeSessionWindows.withGap(Time.minutes(10))`. I need the computation to be performed as soon as last data is obtained from async function.

The best for me is to use the window watermarks from async function, which certainly knows when each query finishes and how mach points it bears. Is this possible and what is the best practice for such a task?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the solution and it appears to be very easy.
I just use EventTime. In my source function i generate event timestamps as well as watermarks as follows:

```java
Long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
ctx.collectWithTimestamp(data, ts);
ctx.emitWatermark(new Watermark(ts + 1));
```

In the stream flow I use EventTime functions:

```java
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
DataStream<...> dataStream = ...;

DataStream<...> newStream = dataStream
    .keyBy(0)
    .timeWindow(Time.milliseconds(1))
    .reduce(new Reducer());
```

In this way I avoid timeouts and the results get ready immediately.